# Display only first 2 pages of pdf in browser

Tags: document

i have uploaded a pdf file using document object in salesforce.
i am using the below code to display that file in my browser.
my requirement is to show only the first two pages of that file in the browser.

```
<apex:repeat var="dc" value="{!details}">
  <tr>
  <td><a target="_blank" href="https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!dc.id}" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 545, 433)"> {!dc.Name} </a></td>
    <td>{!dc.Type}</td>
  </tr> </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. The browser controls how it renders a PDF. No code is loaded when that link is actually clicked. It is just a browser opening a PDF file. If you changed it to use a Visualforce page, there may be something you could do with some fancy CSS (although with renderAs="pdf" it may not work properly).

Comment: is there a solution to the above problem either with embed tag or iframe tag?